# How to properly display Pie Chart in MS Access Form?

Tags: sql, ms-access, charts

Given this **Query**

```
TRANSFORM Count(books.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT books.Category
FROM books
WHERE (((books.Category)='Fantasy'))
GROUP BY books.Category
PIVOT (Switch(books.status=1,'Available',books.status=2,'Reserved',books.status=3,'Unavailable'));
```

that gives this result:

```
Category          Total          Available          Unavailable
Fantasy           116            46                 70
```

I am trying to display it on a Pie Chart which, somehow shows the portion per status together with its value, look like this:

[image]

but instead, I am getting this result:

[image]

I don't know where the **East, West, and North** are coming from. Another thing I observed is in the **Row Source** property why it becomes like this:

```
SELECT [Unavailable],Sum([Available]) AS [SumOfAvailable] FROM [qryGetFantasy] GROUP BY [Unavailable];
```

I am using Office 2013.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Edit question to show some sample data as a text table. The East/West/North are defaults and could eventually be replaced by your data at some point in switching between design/form and saving. Is this a Modern Chart? Unfortunately, I have Access 2010 and so cannot work with Modern Chart.

Comment: Are you saying chart is not correctly displaying data? Once wizard builds chart, should be able to adjust its properties, including the RowSource. So if RowSource should be the CROSSTAB query, paste it into there.

Comment: @June7 My bad, I forgot to switch to a form view that's why it displays the default one. As for the data, I just tweak my queries above to display properly. ```TRANSFORM Count(books.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT Switch(books.[status]=1,'Available',books.[status]=2,'Reserved',books.[status]=3,'Unavailable') AS Status
FROM books
WHERE (((books.category)='Fantasy'))
GROUP BY books.status
PIVOT books.category;```